# Find specific dictionary element without looping

Tags: python

Is there a way in python to check if any dictionary element has a specific value at a specific key, without looping over the entire dictionary?

So, in the following example:

```
 [{
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "Bob",
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Dave",
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Dave",
    }]
```

I would like to get a true/false answer if any there are any elements with the name 'Dave'

Comment: What data type is that supposed to be?  It can't be a set of dictionaries with a missing `{` at the start because dictionaries aren't hashable.

Comment: I think there is a } too much at the end...

Comment: sorry about that - fixed now

Comment: The short answer is no; you haven't organized your data structure in such a way as to make that possible without simply checking each `element['Name'] == 'Dave'`. If you want to do this without looping, you'll need to keep a dict of assigned names somewhere, or otherwise rethink your data structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your data structure doesn't support `O(1)` lookups, so you still have to loop through it:

```
any(d['Name'] == 'Dave' for d in dicts)
```

Passing a generator into `any` lets it short-circuit, so it'll stop once an element is found.

If you need to do this often, you can combine all of the items into a single lookup table:

```
from collections import defaultdict

total = defaultdict(set)

for d in dicts:
    for key, value in d.items():
        total[key].add(value)
```

Now, you can do `O(1)` lookups:

```
'Dave' in total['Name']
```

Comment: So is this any more efficient than writing my own for in and using a break when the first instance is found?

Comment: @MartyWallace: That's exactly what `any` does. I'm passing in a generator, so it'll stop looping once that condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `"Dave" in d.values()` where `d` is your dictionary.

Since you have a list of dictionaries, try:

`any(d.get("Name") == "Dave" for d in my_dicts)`. If one of the dictionaries doesn't have the key `"Name"`, it will be handled (it returns `None` and `None != "Dave"`).

Comment: It has to be specific to the name key though.  I simplified my data in the question